# In Windows (base install) what is the fastest way to search only filenames?

Tags: windows, file-search

In Windows (base install: no extensions, tools, add-on's, or 3rd Party software) what is the fastest native way to search only filenames AND without modifying the "state" of indexing and/or changing the "state" of content search?

The fastest way I know to do this is in [Windows Explorer] to enter in the search box >>>

```
System.FileName:~="SomePartOfTheFilenameHere"
```

...  and because I'm a geek, I'll typically paste the following in the search box >>>

```
System.FileName:~=""
```

...  and then type into the quotes.  I've found that on older machines (especially on a directory with no indexing, but "search in contents ON") even just typing in the box has an impact until `System.FileName:` is fully typed out and causes the mice to spin, but by pasting it in it goes straight into "FileName Only" mode.

Does anyone know a faster / better way?

Comment: Although I don't know for sure, powershell may have some trick up its sleeves.

Comment: `C:\>dir /s /b "filen*.*"` in a command prompt comes to mind.

Comment: @tumchaaditya PowerShell (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx) afaik is not native/core and needs to be installed.  If I'm correct, then in this case it would be excluded for the purposes of this question.  Thanks though.

Comment: @GeoBaj PowerShell is bundled with Windows 7 and later, but has to manually installed in previous operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

## Using the command-line interface

1. While holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, right-click an empty spot in the folder you're in, and choose **Open Command Window Here** (this works in Windows Vista and later).
2. Once the command prompt is open, type or paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   dir *whatever* /a:-d
   ```

   The `/a:-d` parameter will omit directories from the results, thus performing a file-only search. If you want to include subfolders you can use the `/s` parameter:

   ```
   dir *whatever* /a:-d /s
   ```

   By default, the output is quite verbose and includes different information, such as file size or last modified time. To get a bare bones list stripping all extra information, use the `/b` parameter:

   ```
   dir *whatever* /a:-d /b /s
   ```

   You can also search multiple strings. Quotes are required if you use spaces:

   ```
   dir "*some thing*" *whatever* /a:-d /b /s
   ```

### Further reading

- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)

Comment: I recommend adding the /b switch so it only gives a path and filename as result rather than a full header for each folder.

Comment: In a quick search for a file, you want to know its location, usually not when it was modified or how large it is.